# Is it possible to loop through an array of images and generate all of them at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import Card from "./Animation/Components/Card";

const alpha = Math.PI / 6;

const Cards = [
  require("./Animation/images/card1.png"),
  require("./Animation/images/card2.png"),
  require("./Animation/images/card3.png"),
];

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {Cards.map((item, index) => {
        const rotate = index - 1 * alpha;
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={item}
            style={{ transform: [{ rotate: `${rotate}rad` }] }}
          >
            <Card title={item} />
          </Animated.View>
        );
      })}
      <Button title="Toggle" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am trying to loop through an array of pictures to perform an animation on each of the pictures to rotate each image at an angle. With this code, only one of the pictures rotates at a time. I cannot loop and generate all the three pictures at the same time. Any help with this?

Comment: As I know, javascript has only one thread, so no, you can't do anything in parallel. But I'm not sure about react native

Comment: Can you produce a minimal, reproducible example in an [expo snack](https://expo.io/) and share here?